# Classic ASP not working on Windows Vista IIS7

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I have just moved from Windows XP Pro to Windows Vista Ultimate. I installed IIS and all sub categories (including Classic ASP).

I have a few websites in my `wwwroot` folder that are Classic ASP sites. When I try to view them through localhost, I keep getting an error message:

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
>
> If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

This error links off to [this page](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/559/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-70-and-iis-75/), which is about running Classic ASP websites on IIS7.

I have followed the post and enabled ASP in IIS. However, I cannot get the sites to work.

Can anyone please shed some light as to why this is happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me once I added ASP under Programs and Features without any issues..  One thing I noticed is a checkbox to "enable server side includes" so if your ASP app has that, you may want to check that off.

You also may want to check security settings but I didn't have any issues with that either.

I wrote a very complex ASP page with the following source code for a test

```
<%= Response.Write("Hi Stack Overflow") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, that's:

```
ipmo servermanager
add-windowsfeature web-asp
```